# Dispatcher.Invoke preventing app from closing

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I had to add a `Dispatcher.Invoke` to my MVVM Light WPF app (as the bit of code within was called from an event on an external process). However now, when I try to close the app by clicking on the app's cross in the window chrome, it does not close down. I already have a `Dispose()` method getting called when app shutdown is detected so I was thinking that maybe I need to add some code to it to dispose of this `Dispatcher`?

(Note, there are other similar questions but I am too green to adapt to my problem here.)

```
System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(
() =>
{
    .... my code ...
}));
```

Comment: What's in that action?

Comment: Invoke() is a dangerous method, highly likely to cause deadlock.  Any scenario where you try to get the worker thread to stop in, say, an event handler for the Window.Close event is going to lead to tears.  The Invoke() method cannot complete because your UI thread is stuck waiting for the thread to complete, the event handler cannot complete because the thread is stuck.  A deadly embrace called deadlock.  Always favor BeginInvoke(), use Debug + Windows + Threads to diagnose deadlock.

Comment: @HansPassant, thank you BeginInvoke worked

Comment: You are ignoring the elephant.  Well, as long as it works.